# xPath: Select parent element only if child element doesn't contain a certain value

Tags: xml, xpath, filtering

Given this:

```
<element_1> 
    <element_2>Text</element_2> 
    <element_3> 
        <element_4> 
            <element_5>Text with @ in Value</element_5> 
        </element_4> 
        <element_4> 
            <element_5>Test Text</element_5> 
        </element_4> 
    </element_3> 
    <element_6> 
        <element_7> 
            <element_8>0</element_8> 
...
```

How do I select all instances of element_1 that do *not* contain an '@' in element_5?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a general XPath expression that selects all required elements in any document -- when the structure of the document is not known in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
element_1[not(contains(element_3/element_4/element_5,'@'))]
```

This is interpreted as

```
element_1[                          #select elements named "element_1"
  not(contains(                     #that do not contain
    element_3/element_4/element_5,  #children in this hierarchy
    '@'                             #the character @
  ))
]
```

Comment: Does this need leading // before element_1?

Comment: Depends if you want to match element_1 at any level, or if it's always the root of the DOM.

Comment: Also note that this solution assumes that element_5 is always directly beneath element_4, which in turn is always directly beneath element_3, which in turn is always directly beneath element_1. The other two solutions assume that element_5 can appear at any level beneath element_1.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't been able to test this yet, but I think I can figure it out from here if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

My XPath is a bit rusty, but something like this:

```
//element_1[.//element_5[not(contains(., "@"))]]
```

Comment: We are a litle bit picky and don't recommend `//` operator when the schema is wellknown...

Comment: That's fine. The OP wasn't specific about that.

Comment: Why the down-rank? At least have the decency to leave a message saying why you've down-ranked, whoever you are.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I select all instances of
>   element_1 that do not contain an '@'
>   in element_5?

**Use**:

```
//element_1[not(.//element_5[contains(.,'@')])]
```

**In English, this means**: Select all `"element_1"` elements in the document that do not have an `"element_5"` descendant whose string value contains the string `'@'`.

I am using the `//` abbreviation only because the structure of the XML file isn't clear.

I always recommend to avoid using the `//` abbreviation always when this is possible, because otherwise this may result in very inefficient XPath evaluation.

Comment: @Mads-Hansen: Thank you for the edits, but "descendent" is a valid English word.

Answer (score 0):

```
element1[not(contains(.//element_5, '@'))]
```